# For which country price have null values

Tags: python, pandas

**I have imported csv file and find out null values. I have found null values in price 13396.**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Data Analyst\Data Analyst with python\winemag.csv',sep=';')

df.isnull().sum()
```

*country ----- 2*

*price ------- 13396*

**After fill the values using for statement as below still i have found null values in price 5**

```
frames=[]
for i in list(set(df['country'])):
    df_country = df[df['country']==i]
    df_country.price.fillna(df_country.price.mean(),inplace=True)
    frames.append(df_country)
    final_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

*country ---- 0*

*price ------- 5*

**Can you help me to find out for which country price value is null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all prices for one particular country are NaN, the mean of this will return NaN as well.

Try running

```
df1 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

to investigate exactly which rows still have NaN values

Comment: Thanks. Its working to  investigate exactly, but all columns are getting display in result, those have NaN. But I need get values country wise those price values have NaN. I have so many columns, i didn't given information in code. Can you help me to code display result country wise those price values are Nan. I don't want get other columns display in result.

Comment: try df_subset = df[['country', 'price']] and then calculating df1 based on this subset dataframe instead of the original larger one